# Why does Mathematica store numerical values in a fresh kernel?

Tags: numerics, numerical-value

For some reason, when I try to do a computation in a fresh kernel, MM remembers the "old" values from the old kernel, is there a way to stop this?

Comment: You have to give some more information.  Can you give an example of an old value that is remembered on a fresh kernel?

Comment: Also, are you sure that you are shutting down the kernel, not just closing the notebook? I.e. does the problem persist if you use `Quit[]` to quit the kernel?

Comment: @JasonB. An example is the last question I posted here about solving a ODE system. When I copy the symbolic expression(without the numerical values substituted) in a fresh kernel, it gives me the output from the old kernel(where I inputted the numerical values)

Comment: @Hausdorff I haven't tried. however I still need the "old" notebook open so I'm not sure how this will work?

Comment: If you kill the kernel, all info is gone! There is no old value to remember. However, if you still need the old notebook, start a second copy of MMA. Then you have 2 indedendent working environments and you can copy/paste between them.

Comment: @DanielHuber though whether that is possible depends on the license he is using

Comment: @Math - to quit the kernel but leave the notebook open either evaluate `Exit[]` or use the menu `Evaluation` -> `Quit Kernel` -> `Local`